It's more like a simple math question but how does this process to that?

I tried to adjust the equation multiple times to make it look like the second one, but I kept failing. Can someone please let me know how?

$\frac{mg}{k}$ is a constant term not dependent on time and hence if it is differentiated (twice) with respect to time  it becomes zero.
So mathematically the two terms highlighted in yellow only differ by a division by $m$.
The author is changing the variable from $x$ to $x-\frac{mg}{k}$ to make it simpler to solve the differential equation?
